# How to place a div on top of another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a div with text over a div containing in my case the picture element. I can't seem to find out how to solve my current issue. You can see a wrapper div and that containing the div with the image and the text. The thing I have in mind is that the text will go over the image and not be stuck beneath it.

```css
  

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
}
    
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
    
.wrapper__figure {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}


.wrapper__content {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="color: #000;border-color: #ffffff;">
  <figure class="wrapper__figure">
    <div class="wrapper__figure__content">
      <picture>
        <img id="hero-image" style="object-fit: cover;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x800">
      </picture>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="wrapper__content">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="
                   color: #000;
                   border-color: #ffffff;
                 ">
  <figure class="wrapper__figure">
    <div class="wrapper__figure__content">
      <picture>
        <img id="hero-image" style="object-fit: cover;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x800">
      </picture>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="wrapper__content">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

@TylerH thank you for the edit on my post and pointing out that I didn't make use of compiled css.

I now encountered a new issue. Now my code is working I tried to add a new wrapper beneath it, but when doing this the second wrapper goed beneath the first one. The thing I was hoping to aquire was 2 images. I don't seem to find any solution for this myself.

Comment: Why don't you set the image as a background?

Comment: If possible, go for @JonasGrumanns solution. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: `&__content` is not nested under `.wrapper`

Comment: Please compile your code into CSS and post that, unless your issue is specifically with how to do this using your pre-processor (and you actually know how to do it in CSS)

Comment: @Jonas Grumann I want to add alt text to the image. In the former situation I used the background-image, but since this doesn't have alt text I have to do it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had written class wrong. Either do it the way I wrote it now, either add &__content to .wrapper

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  &__figure {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper__content {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.65;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="
                   color: #000;
                   border-color: #ffffff;
                 ">
  <figure class="wrapper__figure">
    <div class="wrapper__figure__content">
      <picture>
        <img id="hero-image" style="object-fit: cover;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x800">
      </picture>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="wrapper__content">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="column1-3">

          <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia
            in, elementum id enim.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have found the solution to my first issue by compiling scss to css.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the wrapper div to contain the text div (wrapper_content), why not just make the wrapper image a background image and position the wrapper_content div over the top with either position absolute or display flex - justify-content-center / align-items-center. Like so:

```
.wrapper {

   background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1920x800');
   background-size: auto;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.wrapper_content {

   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

Or like I said use the display: flex and use the justify-content-center / align-items-center to center the wrapper_content over the wrapper (background-image).

Comment: I am trying to make use of pictures so I can use alt text. This was asked to me so google can find the images by alt text.